# Problema con tgbot en c++ con los controladores y oyentes, y extraña sintaxis en un parametro de funcion

Tags: c++, telegram-bot

Soy relativamente nuevo en c ++, he estado estudiando el lenguaje por un tiempo y como siempre, después de la teoría viene la práctica. Por eso me propuse hacer un bot simple. Al parecer, esto necesita un tipo de controlador o escucha, viendo la documentación encuentro métodos como EventHandler () y HandleUpdate (). El problema es que no sé cómo implementarlo para poder incluir mis funciones (comandos) start y getlink en el proceso. Busque ejemplos, pero sobre todo hay Python. Si alguien puede guiarme con un ejemplo de la implementación del controlador y la funcion update de la biblioteca, estaría muy agradecido.

Por otra parte, una duda muy concreta es sobre el segundo parametro de onCommands(). Nunca habia visto tal sintaxis, es decir... ese [&bot] y tambien que es como si en ese segundo parametro de la funcion onCommands, en realidad sea una funcion de algun modo ya que dentro de esta funcion el segundo parametro abre de nuevo los {}.

Como ven esta segunda duda es tan concreta que cuando intente investigar fue en vano. Asi que este fue mi ultimo recurso.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<tgbot/tgbot.h>    

void start(TgBot::Bot bot){
    bot.getEvents().onCommand("start", [&bot](TgBot::Message::Ptr message){
        bot.getApi().sendMessage(message->chat->id, "Hi everyone !!!");
    });
}

void getlink(TgBot::Bot bot){
    bot.getEvents().onCommand("getlink", [&bot](TgBot::Message::Ptr message){
        bot.getApi().sendMessage(message->chat->id, bot.getApi().exportChatInviteLink(message->chat->id));
    });
}

int main(){
    TgBot::Bot bot("token here");
    TgBot::TgLongPoll longPoll(bot);
    while(true){
        longPoll.start();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Lo de proporcionarte un ejemplo, no está permitido en el sitio. Lo demás, no me queda claro. La parte del código que indicas es una [expresión lambda](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda). ¿ Que es lo que quieres, una explicación de esto ?

Comment: lol, no conocia en c++ sobre lambda. muchas gracias por la documentacion al respecto. En cuanto a lo del ejemplo entiendo. pero almenos sabes donde puedo ver uno o entender mejor esa parte?

Comment: No, lo siento. No he usado nunca el `tgbot` ese :-/